# Set value of input range from array

Tags: javascript

I have a range slider, usual min, max and value. Min and max co-operate nicely, and will use data stored in an array. Try to pull the 'value' from the array, and it doesn't work. I have tried:

```
  thumb=[];
  var thumb[0]=72;
  var thumb[0]="72"; // As a manual test
  var x=thumb[0];
  var x=thumb[0].toString();
  document.getElementById('slider').value=thumb[0];
  document.getElementById('slider').value=thumb[0].value;
  document.getElementById('slider').value=x;
  document.getElementById('slider').value='"'+thumb[0].value+'"';
  document.getElementById('slider').value=''+thumb[0].value;
  document.getElementById('slider').value=thumb[0].toString();
  document.getElementById('slider').value=Number(thumb[0]);
  document.getElementById('slider').setAttribute('value',thumb[0]);
  document.getElementById('slider').setArttribute('value',thumb[0].value);
  document.getElementById('slider').setAttribute('value',x);
```

and virtually every other which way you can think of.

If I use document(getElementById).value="72" (ie hard coded within HTML) works perfectly, but can't get the value from the array. (Thumb keeps jumping to the min value, or sometimes the max value: random)

Although I've shown thumb[0] here, the array has several elements, all set as from values initially created by the slider. But when I try to reload ...

```
(loop)
function saveValues(){
min[line]=document.getElementById('slider').min;
thumb[line]=document.getElementById('slider').value;
max[line]=document.getElementById('slider').max;
createElement('option'); // Abbreviated
line++;
}
(end loop)

// The above createElement
<select id="opt" onchange="setSlider()">
<option>Cap1</option>
<option>Cap2</option> // Adds an entry each time saveValues() is called
</select>

function setSlider(){
var opt= getElementById('opt').selectedIndex;
document.getElementById('slider').min=min[opt];   // OK
document.getElementById('slider').max=max[opt];   // OK
document.getElementById('slider').value=thumb[opt]; // Will not set thumb/value
}

<input type="range" min="0" value="0" max="60" id="slider">
<input type="button" onclick="saveValues()" value="Save settings">
```

Even more bizarre, it seems to work when I select option 0 ... but all the others refuse to set correctly. (I know the min and max are set as they are printed to console as move thumb) I have abbreviated the code as it runs to around 600 lines

Comment: You have to declare the variable just once, exactly at the first line

Answer (score 0):

```
  var thumb[0]=72;
  var thumb[0]="72"; // As a manual test
```

remove var from here. You do not change array, but declare something else

Answer (score 0):

The answer - as always - was staring me in the face! I thought that as "value" was *between* min and max, that's the place it should be in code. Wrong! You have to set min and max *first* so that it knows what range it has to work with, and it can then calculate the position of the thumb in relation to the others.

Just per chance I happened to pick up on this on another site ... and seems obvious now!